# List All Files in Directory React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am using React.js with Node.js and am trying to serve the client a list of all the files in my (the server's) `public` folder. I created the app using `create-react-app`.

I tried using `fs` but I understood that React is run in a browser environment and that blocks access to file handling so that won't work. After scouring around SO and so many other forums, the closest I got was using `require.context` but it would return objects with the correct names (of the files) but I couldn't find any way to extract the text from those objects. My code is

```
const importAll = r => r.keys().map(r);

const files = importAll(require.context('./path/to/folder/', false, /\.*$/));

console.log(files);
```

I am new to React and web dev in general so I might be missing something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: browser doesn't have file system access yet and even if it does it'll have access to user's local files not the ones on your server. You need to turn that into an api endpoint and let nodejs do the reading and just return that to your react app.

Comment: so i should use `fetch`?

Comment: Yes but only when you have your API endpoint ready. Then you use `fetch` to communicate with the said endpoint.

Comment: how can i create an endpoint?

Comment: Google "create nodejs api endpoints" and enjoy the endeavor.

Comment: This is an architectural misconception as pointed by @SamR. You need to create a second application that will not have the graphical interface (API) and in that application with an exposed endpoint your front will be able to list the files.

Comment: so when rendering the page in my original project, i should be fetching from my api which should be a separate project?

Comment: when u provide the project over node ur already using express i think so u can create in the nodejs application also a path which reads the dir and supply a json file for react with fetch. U can also precreate this json file and put it to the dir where ur react application is and fetch it.